# Property files in Restful web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest

In Restful web service, If suppose I want to get the values from some property files means where I need to keep those .property files in war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my problem by adding

```
       InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(propertiesFileName);
        if(inputStream != null) {
            properties.load(inputStream);
        }
```

this code. When my war file is currently running on any application server.

Answer (score 0):

You can read any .properties you like in your REST service implementation using getResourceAsStream().

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply Duffymo, While creating .war file (for server deployment purpose) where i keep my .properties file inside the .war file

Comment: In my war file runs in localhost 8080 means what path i need to give for loading the property file

Comment: You should read about how to do this.  The path is relative to the CLASSPATH.